# Wordpress contact form: Want to create a contact form to allow hidden field which gets value dynamically from page or url params

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

page content :

```
[contact-form-7 id="6" title="Reserve Restaurant" enquiry-type="reserve"]
```

how to pass the the attribute enquiry-type to contact form

Comment: page content :

[contact-form-7 id="6" title="Reserve Restaurant" enquiry-type="reserve"]

how to pass the the attribute enquiry-type to contact form

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of [CF7](https://contactform7.com/getting-default-values-from-the-context/)  you can get values from the context.

If you have an URL like this

```
http://example.com/page/?customhiddenvalue=Kosar+Latif
```

You can read the value from the URL params into the hidden field like this

```
[hidden customhiddenvalue default:get]
```

Alternatively, you can use [Contact Form 7 Dynamic Text Extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/) plugin